# Spring Controller redirect to another page

Tags: java, ajax, spring, redirect, controller

Hey I got the following problem.
This is the content of the jspx file:

```
function postSMTH() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: document.getElementById("urltxt").value,
        data: parameters,

        });
}

<input type="hidden" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/foo/foo2/foodat" name="urltxt" id="urltxt"/>

<div class="foodat"><a href="javascript:postSMTH();"><spring:message code="foo_foo2_foodat_text" text="FOODAT"/></a></div>
```

So if I push the submit button, the `postSMTH` function is called and the ajax object is paste to the Controller which look like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/foo")
public class FooController {

..............

@RequestMapping(value="/foo2", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String homePOST(HttpServletRequest request) {
    ........
}    
@RequestMapping(value="/foo2", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String homeGET(HttpServletRequest request) {
    ........
} 


@RequestMapping(value="/foo2/foodat", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String doTHAT(HttpServletRequest request) {
    //  check authorization

        Map fooMap = request.getParameterMap();

        // do something in the Database, depending on the paramMap

    return "redirect:/foo/foo1";
}
}
```

Everything is working fine regarding the Database, but the Problem is, that the redirect at the end DOESN'T work. It just stays at the page foo2.

I'm new to Spring, maybe its a little mistake somewhere. I just cant make it out by myself.

Would be nice if someone would have some hint. Thanks

Comment: Could be some exception happening and redirect not being called. Did you add log/System.out and see last statement is being called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are making asynchronous form submission using jquery ajax call. So, after your request is completed you need to change the document location using javascript. E.g., something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: document.getElementById("urltxt").value,
    data: parameters,
    complete: function() {
        window.location.replace(...);
      }
  });
```

Comment: In this case you should accept the answer or give some credit. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not redirecting because you are submitting via ajax.  You'll need to handle the redirect yourself.  Perhaps this very popular question will help. [How to manage a redirect request after a jQuery Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call)