# Spring MVC: Redirect in @ResponseBody

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I want to redirect to another .jsp in spring mvc method. I don't want to use javascripts methods like: window.location.replace(url).

My method:

```
@RequestMapping(value= "loginUser", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String loginUser (@RequestParam("name") String name,   @RequestParam("password") String password){ 

   return "";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do the redirect from Spring when your request expects json response. You can set a parameter for redirect so that when you enter the success block you can check the parameter to redirect using `window.location.reload();`. For example, from a similar post, check this answer,

[Redirect on Ajax Jquery Call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2927044/1793718)

> One idea is to let the the browser know that it should redirect by
>   adding a redirect variable to to the resulting object and checking for
>   it in JQuery
>
> ```
> $(document).ready(function(){ 
>     jQuery.ajax({ 
>         type: "GET", 
>         url: "populateData.htm", 
>         dataType:"json", 
>         data:"userId=SampleUser", 
>         success:function(response){ 
>             if (response.redirect) {
>                 window.location.href = response.redirect;
>             }
>             else {
>                 // Process the expected results...
>             }
>         }, 
>      error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
>             alert('Error!  Status = ' + xhr.status); 
>          } 
>
>     }); 
> });
> ```

You can alternatively add a response header for redirect like `response.setHeader("REQUIRES_AUTH", "1")` and in jQuery success,

> ```
> success:function(response){ 
>         if (response.getResponseHeader('REQUIRES_AUTH') === '1'){ 
>             window.location.href = 'login.htm'; 
>         }
>         else {
>             // Process the expected results...
>         }
>     }
> ```

Refer the similar question: [Spring Controller redirect to another page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10899072/1793718)

Comment: @OrangeDog seems it won't working either. As spring doesn't redirect to another page on json requests. Updated an alternative solution.

Comment: Who said it was an async request?

Comment: I assumed the OP is using ajax call to login the user and redirect to some success page. Anyway whether or not he uses ajax, it can only be done is JS as the other posts suggests.

Answer (score 3):

Include an `HttpServletResponse` parameter and call [`sendRedirect(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect-java.lang.String-).

Or, don't use `@ResponseBody` at all, and return the model/view you want to use.

Comment: @Responsebody is essential in my case, I included an HttpServletResponse and called sendRedirect(String) and it dosen't work. :(

Comment: Are you sure it's essential? What do you return when this call doesn't redirect?

Comment: else { response.sendRedirect(TApi.Navigation.ANOTHER_JSP); }

                response.sendRedirect(TApi.Navigation.GET_APP_PAGE);